# Landscape mode for the flacard class

Tags: geometry, landscape, flashcards

I'm using the [flacards](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/flacards) document class to create flashcards.

When I try and make the document landscape using geometry (`\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}`) I get the following error:

`! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.`

Consequently, I can't get my flashcards to print in a landscape orientation. Has anybody got a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the [`flacards` document class](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flacards) already loads the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) with a set of options:

```
\RequirePackage[noheadfoot, margin=1cm, outer=1cm, inner=1cm]{geometry}
```

Instead of "re-loading `geometry`", just set the new values:

```
\geometry{landscape}
```